# Replacement to network-manager-openvpn-gnome

Tags: networking, gnome, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

Is there any modern GUI equivalent of network-manager-openvpn-gnome on ubuntu? Something like TunnelBlick in MacOS?

Why i ask?
Over the past few months, the default manager has ceased to be useful in any way. Bugs cause, that application not add routing entries, can not import data from * .ovpn file  ("unknown errors" ?!!) and I slowly have enough juggling vpns in the console.

This is doubly annoying when colleagues using eg. Antergos do not have any of these problems (with the same ovpn files!!!).

P.S. A [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/1603600) related to the routing table in two weeks will have a birthday and nothing is going to happen to him.

Comment: You are out of luck. No.

Answer (score 1):

Give Pritunl client a spin https://github.com/pritunl/pritunl-client and http://client.pritunl.com/